# Cannot get rid of extra search bar and login and register buttons

Tags: angular

```js
<app-navi>test1</app-navi>
<router-outlet>test2</router-outlet>
<body>test3</body>
```

```html
<div class="navibg">
    <div class="flex-form">
        <input [(ngModel)]="name" class="srcBar" type="search" placeholder="Search by title" required>
            <button (click)="search()" class="srcBtn" type="submit">Search</button>
                <span class="welcome">Welcome to Movie Search!!</span>
                    <span class="btns">
                        <button class='logBtn'>Log In</button>
                            <a routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active" class='regiBtn'>Register</a>
                    </span>  
                this is navi
    </div>
</div>
```

**my router.ts**

```
export const router: Routes = 
[ { path: '', component: AppComponent }, 
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, 
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }, 
  { path: 'navi', component: NaviComponent }, ];
```

I cannot get rid of extra search bar and etc.
I think  causing the error.
Once I deleted the app-router, then router doesn't work.
Please advice.
Thank you.

[image: Duplicate entry]

Comment: Can you post the code or the error ... it's better than the image . Otherwise this question is difficult to answer

Comment: Hi, there is no error message for this one.

Comment: can you post the app.component or your root component. I think you have by mistake loaded the root component in your router-outlet , that why it's showing duplicate. Please share the routing

Comment: I got the issue , there must a line in your routing module where you are using `{Path:"/",Component:"with selector app-navi"}` . This is causing the `app-navi` component again to be loaded in the `<router-outlet>` That's why it's showing twice. You should only load child component and not your root component for your default route as the child components are usually present inside root component.

Comment: This is my router.ts


export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '',  component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'navi', component: NaviComponent },
];

Comment: The problem is in this line `{ path: '', component: AppComponent }`, replace AppComponent  with any other component which you want to show on the home page and at the root of your site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!
What if I want to use the app.component as a home??

It worked anyway!! thank you! I spent 10hours for this.....

Comment: Can I post it as answer? app.component is your root component so all your component should be rendered so it's by default your home page. You only need to render your child components inside that app.component  using `router-outlet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your routing structure , you are loading `AppComponent` as the default route for your page. But `AppComponent` is your root component which  includes `router-outlet` and  navigation menu. Hence the navigation menu is rendered as duplicate inside the `router-outlet`. You should replace the below line in router.ts -

`{ path: '', component: AppComponent }` with `{ path: '', component: <any other child component>}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is with the line below in the routes.

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent }
```

You can probably give some other component like/similar to **HomePageComponent** if it's there.